# Get error Controller method not found in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, routes

I have a problem with routes in laravel. Do you have any idea? This is my code.

My jquery to send variable:

```js
$('.del').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var actor = $('#actor').val();
            var url = "{{Asset('lesson/delete-chapter')}}";
            var url_dir ="{{Asset('lesson/view')}}"+actor;  //this just url to direct after del
            $.get(url,{id:id},function(data){   
                alert(data);
                $(location).attr("href",url_dir);
            });
        }
        return false;
});
```

This is my routes:

```
Route::get('lesson/delete-chapter','LessonController@postDeleteChapter');
```

This is my controller:

```
 public function postDeleteChapter(){
        $id = Input::get('id');

        $less = Lesson::where('chapter_id','=',$id);
        if(count($less)>0){
            $data['re'] = "Please delete lessons in this chapter!";
        }
        else{
            $chapter = Chapter::find($id);
            $less->delete();
            $data['re'] = "Deleted!";
        }
        echo json_decode($data);
    }
```

It's get error with routes delete, I dont know why, can you help me? Thanks you very much.

Comment: You should call first() or get() method after the the where method, otherwise no query will be executed, you could also use the Eloquent's count method instead of using the count function. That being said, why are you calling delete on the $less row when it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use `url` function instead of `asset`.

```
$('.del').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var actor = $('#actor').val();
            var url = "{{url('lesson/delete-chapter')}}";
            var url_dir ="{{url('lesson/view')}}"+actor;  //this just url to direct after del
            $.get(url,{id:id},function(data){   
                alert(data);
                $(location).attr("href",url_dir);
            });
        }
        return false;
});
```